# saving short animations for dropping into timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

Simple question: is there a way I can make a short animation, say that last for 50 frames, store that animation so it doesn't play on the timeline, but is saved, such that I can later drop it into the timeline at a desired location and have it play? Ideally it would also stack with other animations.
Something similar to shape keys would also work, where I can pull a slider to go from one state to another, but with transforms outside of edit mode

Comment: Have you looked into Dope Sheet and Nonlinear Animation editors? It sounds like this is what you want, no?